# Selecting an entity based off a compare condition in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. These are not them but it is the same principle:

```
Table:One (artists)
--------------
id (Primary Key)
name
best genre

Table:Two (artist teams)
-------------
id1 (Foreign Key)
id2 (Foreign Key)
```

I want to select the artist teams where their favorite genres are the same.

My work so far is

```
SELECT *
FROM Two INNER JOIN One
WHERE ( ).
```

Im confused as to what to put in the WHERE statement. 
I have no idea how to compare the values of the artist's genres to each other!

```
pseudo code for WHERE:
retrieve id#1's favourite genre 
retrieve id#2's favourite genre
compare them
if equal display the related entity from table Two
```

I've searched for a while looking for a solution and I can't find anything
just like this, I believe it could be a bit a syntax that im missing. 
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You need multiple joins to the "artists" table:

```
select t.*, a1.genre
from teams t join
     artists a1
     on t.id1 = a1.id join
     artists a2
     on t.id2 = a2.id and a2.genre = a1.genre;
```